# Using AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC ng-repeat is empty in table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML table as following:

```
   <div class="form-group" ng-controller="GetStudentController">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover form-group">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Student ID
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Ime
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Prezime
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="s in data track by $index">
                        <td>
                            {{s.StudentID}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{s.Ime}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{s.Prezime}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

And I have setup small angular module/service and controller for my experiment. As backend service I'm using C# and as front-end I'm using AngularJS to fetch my data and display it on the view as following:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service("GetStudentsService", function ($http) {
    this.getData = function ()
    {
        return $http({
            metod: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetStudent"
        }).success(function (data) {
            return data;
        }).error(function () {
            alert("error");
            return null;
        });
    }
});
app.controller("GetStudentController", function ($scope, GetStudentsService) {
    $scope.data = null;
    GetStudentsService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response;
    });
});
```

And this is my service:

```
  public JsonResult GetStudent()
        {
            return new JsonResult { Data = Connection.dc.Students.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

Angular fetches the data okay, but its not binding it within the {{}} brackets... I've checked in console for signs of errors, but nothing appears to be wrong... The table is displayed like this:

[image]

Does anyone knows why this is happening?? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
$scope.data = response.data;
```

Comment: It works now, but could you be more specific with the answer please? Whats the difference between $scope.data=  response; and $scope.data = response.data??

Comment: when you use .success with data only it is need but if you use .success with 4 arguments, like .success(function(data,status,header,config){}) here you will get data directly